# Replace an empty values in Array of Objects with the previous filled values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and some values of the object are empty and I want to replace them with the values of the previous object, here is an example :

```
[
  {
    name: "Mark",
    surname: "Something",
  },
  {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Richard",
    surname: "SomeSurname",
  },
  {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
  },
];
```

my goal is to replace the empty value with previous ones like that :

```
[
  {
    name: "Mark",
    surname: "Something",
  },
  {
    name: "Mark",
    surname: "Something",
  },
  {
    name: "Richard",
    surname: "SomeSurname",
  },
  {
    name: "Richard",
    surname: "SomeSurname",
  },
];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A `for` loop would be enough.

Comment: Why is this tagged with `node.js`, `json` and `csv`? None of those tags are relevant for the question.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. SO isn't a free code writing service. The objective here is for you to post your attempts to solve your own issue and others help when they don't work as expected. See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: because originally the data that I have is CSV, I am converting it with a nodejs package to have it as an object ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const a = [
  {
    name: "Mark",
    surname: "Something"
  },{
    name: "",
    surname: "" 
  },{
    name: "Richard",
    surname: "SomeSurname"
  },{
    name: "",
    surname: ""
  }
];
for (let i = 0; i < Math.trunc(a.length / 2); ++i) {
  a[2 * i + 1].name = a[2 * i].name;
  a[2 * i + 1].surname = a[2 * i].surname;
}
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Why does this question, that doesn't show any attempts of OP, deserve an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'd run over the list and save the index of the last non-empty object os far, and then update the values to it when I encounter an empty one:

```js
const list = [
  {
    name: "Mark",
    surname: "Something",
  },
  {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Richard",
    surname: "SomeSurname",
  },
  {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
  },
];

let emptyIndex = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; ++i) {
  if (list[i].name) {
    fullIndex = i;
  } else {
    list[i].name = list[fullIndex].name;
    list[i].surname = list[fullIndex].surname;
  }
}

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const array = [
  {
    name: "Mark",
    surname: "Something",
  },
  {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
  },
  {
    name: "Richard",
    surname: "SomeSurname",
  },
  {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
  },
];

//create new array with map es6
let newArray = array.map( (obj,index) => { 
  if( !obj.name && !obj.surname ){
    //if values are empty, create a new one with the previous index
    return { name: array[index-1].name, surname: array[index-1].surname }
  }
  //else return original value
  return obj
})

console.log( newArray );
```